# UITableView scrolling to last cell only displays half of the cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I want to scroll to the bottom of my tableview that contains custom cells.

Here is the code I am using to scroll:

```
NSIndexPath *lastMessage = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.conversation.messages count]-1 inSection:0];
[self.messageTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:lastMessage atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

This scrolls the view; however only the very top of the last cell is visible with ~3/4 of the cell still below the fold that I have to manually scroll down to. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: is your entire table view visible? Is there anything under your tableview, e.g. a tab bar?

Comment: Yep entire table view is visible. Once the scrolltorowatindexpath method finishes I simply have to use my finger to finish scrolling all the way down. There is a view under the tableview, but the frames do not overlap

Comment: is this tableview in your xib file(or nub file) or is it created in code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turned out to be a timing issue. The tableview hadn't fully rendered yet when I called that method from viewdidload (contentsize of 0). Calling this method in viewDidAppear works brilliantly though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the UITableView is confused about how big your cells are. Set the `rowHeight` property on the UITableView to the height of your custom cell.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.. for people in the future it is important for custom cells to do this as Sanjit says. Personally I do this through -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath