# UIKit - UICollectionView - presents only half of the last cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I have a horizontal **UICollectionView** with custom **UICollectionViewCell** with **UILabel**

-which I've built with the interface builder **storyboard** + **xib** file for the cell)

I want to have some space between the cells - so I've set *"Min Spacing"* to 10 (*for lines*)

also **Estimate Size** is set to :
*120 width, 25 Height*

The problem is:  when I scroll to the end, the last cell is being cut, and only half of it is being presented, as shown in the picture:

[image]

### EDIT (Constraints):

Constraints on the **UICollectionView** are (with the interface builder):
Align Top to: Safe Area (8 to the top)
Align Trailing to: Safe Area (0 to the right)
Align Leading to : Safe Area (0 to the left)
Height Equals: 60

### Tried this:

settings the ***Right Section Insets*** to 100, but that only worked for a constant number of tags.

### also found this post:

*[UITableView scrolling to last cell only displays half of the cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906750/uitableview-scrolling-to-last-cell-only-displays-half-of-the-cell)*

but it's a different case (programmatically built tableview with manual scroll) and also a different language (obj-c)

Comment: What constraints are applied to your collection view?  It Looks like you may have swapped the trailing anchor of the collection view and the trailing anchor of the superview or have/need a - sign in the constraint value; The edge of the collection view is off screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I set **Min Spacing** back to 0 and also **Section Insets** to 0

I figured the best solution would be setting the spacing INSIDE the cell.

so I went to the **xib** file, added a view container to wrap the label, and set the label's constraints to be 8 on the sides.

this way - the collectionView "thinks" the cell is wider, and you get the space between the cells.

[image]